# Jquery duda acerca de encontrar elementos especificos

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo un problema y es que he creado una tabla con javascript, entonces lo que yo he hecho es que cada vez que introduzco un nombre, apellido y teléfono válido lo añado a la tabla. Entonces no sé como poner que solamente me elija el nombre.

Lo que pasa que cuando pongo por ejemplo **"ro"** para que me busque el nombre de **"roberto"** me borra todas las filas y no sé porque motivo.

Por lo demás no estoy seguro si puede haber algún fallo más.
Lo que se supone que hace el filtrado es mirar que letras has puesto en el input que está fuera del formulario y compararlo con cada una de las filas que se crean en la tabla y después elimina las filas que no cumplen la condición del filtro.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <meta name="author" content="axel">
            <title>Examen. Ejercicio 2</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="../agenda_javascript_y_jquery/ejercicio_2.js"></script>
            <script src="../agenda_javascript_y_jquery/filtrar_contactos.js"></script>
            
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>filtrado contactos</h1>
            <form action="ejemplo.php" method="post" value = "">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>agenda</legend>
                    <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="nombre">
                    <label for="apellido">Apellido:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="apellido">
                    <label for="telephone">Teléfono:</label>
                    <input type="tel" id="telephone">
        
        
        
                    <input type="button" onclick="add()" value="Añadir">
                    <input type="button" onclick="listarElArray()" value="Listar array">
                    <input type="button" onclick="borrarElArray()" value="Borrar array">
                    
                
                    
                </fieldset>
            </form>
            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="text" id = "filtrado">
            <button type="button" id ="button1">Filtrar</button>
        
        
            <table id="registros">
              
                <tr>
                    <th>Nombre</th>
                    <th>Apellido</th>
                    <th>Teléfono</th>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Aquí el filtrado

```
        $( () => {
            // Bindea el CTA directo al botón
            $(document).on('click', '#button1', function(){
              // Sacamos el valor y lo pasamos a minusculas para manejarlo
              const value = $('#filtrado').val().toLowerCase();
              // Obtenemos todas las celdas con los nombres
              $('td').each( function() {
                const name = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
                // Guardamos el <tr> padre de la celda del nombre
                const row  = $(this).parent('tr');
                // Si existe coincidencia, lo muestra, caso contrario lo oculta
                name.includes( value ) ? row.show() : row.hide();
              });
              
            });
          
          
          } )
```

Aquí creo la tabla con javascript donde voy añadiendo cada una de las filas cada vez que escribo los valores en el formulario

```
    // Aquí creo los arrays vacios donde meto los registros del formulario en cada correspondiente array.
    var nombres = []
    var telefonos = []
    var apellidos = []
    
    function add() {
        debugger
        var mensaje = ""
        var nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value
        var apellido = document.getElementById("apellido").value
        var telefono = document.getElementById("telephone").value;
    
    // Validación del nombre, apellido y teléfono
        if (/\D{3}/.test(nombre) == false) {
            mensaje += "\n-Nombre (3 caracteres de TEXTO o mas)\n";
        }
    
        if (/\D{4}/.test(apellido) == false) {
            mensaje += "\n-Apellido (4 caracteres o mas)\n";
        }
    
        if(/^\d{9}$/.test(telefono) == false) {
            mensaje += "\n[INCORRECTO] Introduce un número de teléfono correcto\n";
        }
    
    // Aquí introduzco cada elemento en su array correspondiente
        if (mensaje == "") {
            nombres.push(nombre)
            telefonos.push(telefono)
            apellidos.push(apellido)
            alert("Los elementos han sido añadidos a la tabla")
        }
    // Si los campos no son correctos, salta un error con los campos que hay que cambiar
        else {
            mensaje = "Los siguientes campos se encuentran vacios o no son validos" + mensaje
            alert(mensaje)
            return false
        }
    }
    function listarElArray() {
        var tabla = document.getElementById("registros")
        if (nombres.length == 0) {
            alert("La lista esta vacia")
        }
        else {
            // Aquí se crean cada una de las filas en la tabla para insertar los registros
            for (contador = tabla.rows.length; contador > 1; contador--) {
                tabla.deleteRow(contador - 1)
            }
            for (indice = 0; indice < nombres.length; indice++) {
                var fila = tabla.insertRow(indice + 1)
                var celda = fila.insertCell(0)
                celda.innerHTML = nombres[indice]
                var celda = fila.insertCell(1)
                celda.innerHTML = apellidos[indice]
                var celda = fila.insertCell(2)
                celda.innerHTML = telefonos[indice]
            }
        }
    }
    function borrarElArray() {
        var tabla = document.getElementById("registros")
        if (nombres.length == 0) {
            alert("La lista esta vacia")
        }
        // Aquí se borra el registro que has creado en el formulario
        else {
            for (contador = tabla.rows.length; contador > 1; contador--) {
                tabla.deleteRow(contador - 1)
            }
            nombres = []
            telefonos = []
            apellidos = []
        }
    }
```

Comment: Creo que lo intentó pero está perdido en cómo crear selectores complejos y algunos otros trucos. Pienso que es válida su pregunta

Answer (score 1):

Te comparto un ejemplo que te puede funcionar, te dejé documentado el Jquery para que te sea más fácil

```js
$( () => {
  // Bindea el CTA directo al botón
  $(document).on('click', 'button', function(){
    // Sacamos el valor y lo pasamos a minusculas para manejarlo
    const value = $('input').val().toLowerCase();
    // Obtenemos todas las celdas con los nombres
    $('.nameSearch').each( function() {
      const name = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
      // Guardamos el <tr> padre de la celda del nombre
      const row  = $(this).parent('tr');
      // Si existe coincidencia, lo muestra, caso contrario lo oculta
      name.includes( value ) ? row.show() : row.hide();
    });
    
  });


} )
```

```css
table {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
<button type="button">Buscar</button>
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Apellido</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="nameSearch">John</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="nameSearch">Joana</td>
      <td>Betancourt</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="nameSearch">Omar</td>
      <td>Barrera</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hola Alberto estoy de acuerdo el problema es que yo la tabla la he creado con javascript entonces lo que yo he hecho es que cada vez que introduzco un nombre, apellido y teléfono válido lo añado a la tabla, entonces no sé como poner la clase "nameSearch" solamente en el nombre

Comment: @Axel22 Pon la forma y el código en como estás creando la tabla en la pregunta, que por esa falta de información se ha cerrado tambien, y así podré votar para reabrirla, si es que no faltan más datos. Pulsa sobre en enlace Editar que aparece en el pie de la pregunta para actualizarla con los datos que faltan... ¿entiendes ahora porque se ha cerrado?  Si no poneis todos los datos ocurren cosas como estas y mucha gente puede perder el tiempo intentando ayudar a ciegas. Léete [ask] y haz el [tour] para aprender cómo funciona este sitio, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

En esta respuesta vamos a agregar una **clase** en la columna del nombre para luego realizar el filtro *delimitado a solo esa columna*, el cual efectuaremos con **expresiones regulares** para hacerlo insensible a mayúsculas y minúsculas.

Estos son los cambios a realizar:

1. Donde pones esto:

```javascript
$( () => {
  // Bindea el CTA directo al botón
  $(document).on('click', 'button', function(){
    // Sacamos el valor y lo pasamos a minusculas para manejarlo
    const value = $('input').val().toLowerCase();
    // Obtenemos todas las celdas con los nombres
    $('.nameSearch').each( function() {
      const name = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
      // Guardamos el <tr> padre de la celda del nombre
      const row  = $(this).parent('tr');
      // Si existe coincidencia, lo muestra, caso contrario lo oculta
      name.includes( value ) ? row.show() : row.hide();
    });
    
  });
} )
```

puedes cambiarlo por esto:

```javascript
$(document).on('click', '#button1', function() {
  const value = $('#filtrado').val();
  $('#registros tr').hide()
  $('#registros tr').first().show()
  $('.nombre').each(function(index) {
    var regexObj = new RegExp(value, "gi");
    if (regexObj.test(this.innerText)) {
      $(this).parent().show()
    }
  })
});
```

2. Y donde pones esto:

```javascript
      celda.innerHTML = nombres[indice]
```

le agregas una línea más para agregar la clase a esa columna:

```javascript
      celda.innerHTML = nombres[indice]
      celda.classList.add('nombre')
```

### **Explicación**

- Primero recuperamos el valor del campo de filtro mediante

```
const value = $('#filtrado').val();
```

el cual nos da igual como esté escrito, porque al usar expresiones regulares le diremos que no haga caso a mayúsculas ni minúsculas

- Después escondemos todas las filas, usando [hide()](https://api.jquery.com/hide/), que ya iremos mostrando segun el bucle del filtro se vaya ejecutando:

```javascript
$('#registros tr').hide()
```

- Pero sucede un problema, que la cabecera de la tabla también es una fila, y es la primera, por lo tanto la mostramos de nuevo con [show()](https://api.jquery.com/show/):

```javascript
$('#registros tr').first().show()
```

- Luego iniciamos un bucle mediante la función [each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) de todos los elementos que contengan la clase `name`, de este modo:

```javascript
  $('.nombre').each(function(index) {
```

- A continuación, creamos un objeto de expresión regular con un objeto [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) de este modo:

```javascript
var regexObj = new RegExp(value, "gi");
```

donde:

- **value** es el patron a buscar
- **gi** son las opciones de búsqueda, donde **g** significa global (buscará todas las coincidencias en la cadena, aunque no creo que sea necesario en este caso) e **i** significa case insensitive (insensible a mayúsculas/minúsculas)
- Dentro del bucle comprobamos si el contenido de la columna contiene el valor a buscar mediante esta instrucción, usando el método [test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test):

```javascript
if (regexObj.test(this.innerText)) {
```

y si es cierta, mostramos toda la fila que previamente habiamos escondido, pero solo esa (de momento, hasta el siguiente ciclo):

```javascript
      $(this).parent().show()
```

Fijarse que como la clase `name` está en el elemento `td` debemos retroceder al nivel superior para mostrar toda la fila mediante [parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/), de otro modo sólo nos mostraria la columna sola.

- Por último, para diferenciar la columna de los nombres del resto, se ha incluido la clase `nombre` en la función `listarElArray`, después de rellenar su columna con el innerHTML que ya existía en el código de la pregunta, aprovechando el mismo objeto `celda` ya creado. Todo eso usando el método add() de la propiedad [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/classList):

```javascript
      celda.innerHTML = nombres[indice]
      celda.classList.add('nombre')
```

Cuando termine de iterar todos los ciclos se mostraran todas las filas con los nombres que coinciden parcial o totalmente con el valor del campo de filtro.

Aquí dejo un snippet con todo puesto funcionando para que se pueda probar su ejecución correcta:

```js
// Bindea el CTA directo al botón
$(document).on('click', '#button1', function() {
  const value = $('#filtrado').val();
  $('#registros tr').hide()
  $('#registros tr').first().show()
  $('.nombre').each(function(index) {
    var regexObj = new RegExp(value, "gi");
    if (regexObj.test(this.innerText)) {
      $(this).parent().show()
    }
  })
});

// Aquí creo los arrays vacios donde meto los registros del formulario en cada correspondiente array.
var nombres = []
var telefonos = []
var apellidos = []

function add() {
  // debugger
  var mensaje = ""
  var nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value
  var apellido = document.getElementById("apellido").value
  var telefono = document.getElementById("telephone").value;

  // Validación del nombre, apellido y teléfono
  if (/\D{3}/.test(nombre) == false) {
    mensaje += "\n-Nombre (3 caracteres de TEXTO o mas)\n";
  }

  if (/\D{4}/.test(apellido) == false) {
    mensaje += "\n-Apellido (4 caracteres o mas)\n";
  }

  if (/^\d{9}$/.test(telefono) == false) {
    mensaje += "\n[INCORRECTO] Introduce un número de teléfono correcto\n";
  }

  // Aquí introduzco cada elemento en su array correspondiente
  if (mensaje == "") {
    nombres.push(nombre)
    telefonos.push(telefono)
    apellidos.push(apellido)
    alert("Los elementos han sido añadidos a la tabla")
  }
  // Si los campos no son correctos, salta un error con los campos que hay que cambiar
  else {
    mensaje = "Los siguientes campos se encuentran vacios o no son validos" + mensaje
    alert(mensaje)
    return false
  }
}

function listarElArray() {
  var tabla = document.getElementById("registros")
  if (nombres.length == 0) {
    alert("La lista esta vacia")
  } else {
    // Aquí se crean cada una de las filas en la tabla para insertar los registros
    for (contador = tabla.rows.length; contador > 1; contador--) {
      tabla.deleteRow(contador - 1)
    }
    for (indice = 0; indice < nombres.length; indice++) {
      var fila = tabla.insertRow(indice + 1)
      var celda = fila.insertCell(0)
      celda.innerHTML = nombres[indice]
      celda.classList.add('nombre')
      var celda = fila.insertCell(1)
      celda.innerHTML = apellidos[indice]
      var celda = fila.insertCell(2)
      celda.innerHTML = telefonos[indice]
    }
  }
}

function borrarElArray() {
  var tabla = document.getElementById("registros")
  if (nombres.length == 0) {
    alert("La lista esta vacia")
  }
  // Aquí se borra el registro que has creado en el formulario
  else {
    for (contador = tabla.rows.length; contador > 1; contador--) {
      tabla.deleteRow(contador - 1)
    }
    nombres = []
    telefonos = []
    apellidos = []
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Examen. Ejercicio 2</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>filtrado contactos</h1>
  <form action="ejemplo.php" method="post" value="">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>agenda</legend>
      <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
      <input type="text" id="nombre">
      <label for="apellido">Apellido:</label>
      <input type="text" id="apellido">
      <label for="telephone">Teléfono:</label>
      <input type="tel" id="telephone">
      <input type="button" onclick="add()" value="Añadir">
      <input type="button" onclick="listarElArray()" value="Listar array">
      <input type="button" onclick="borrarElArray()" value="Borrar array">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="filtrado">
  <button type="button" id="button1">Filtrar</button>
  <table id="registros">
    <tr>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Apellido</th>
      <th>Teléfono</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```